# Swift Error: Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'pChData' is a 'let' constant

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift2

I have a function that looks like the following:

```
func receivedData(pChData: UInt8, andLength len: CInt) {
    var receivedData: Byte = Byte()
    var receivedDataLength: CInt = 0

    memcpy(&receivedData, &pChData, Int(len));  // Getting the error here
    receivedDataLength = len
    AudioHandler.sharedInstance.receiverAudio(&receivedData, WithLen: receivedDataLength)
}
```

Getting the error:

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'pChData' is a 'let' constant

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Though none of the arguments which I am passing here are `let` constants. Why am I getting this?

Comment: Where is memcpy() function?

Comment: Does your function need to be able to mutate pChData inside *and* outside its scope? Or only inside? It isn't clear from your question. Be careful to not use inout if you only need the value to be a variable *inside*.

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar `memcpy()´ is a function defined in `Darwin.C.string`. One of its uses is modifying an MTLBuffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to access/modify `pChData` argument, which you can't unless or until you declare it as `inout` parameter. Learn more about `inout` parameter [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/inout-swift). So try with the following code.

```
func receivedData(inout pChData: UInt8, andLength len: CInt) {
    var receivedData: Byte = Byte()
    var receivedDataLength: CInt = 0

    memcpy(&receivedData, &pChData, Int(len));
    receivedDataLength = len
    AudioHandler.sharedInstance.receiverAudio(&receivedData, WithLen: receivedDataLength)
}
```

Comment: In Swift4，pChData should declared as 'pChData: inout UInt8'.

Answer (score 8):

Arguments passed to a function are immutable inside the function by default.

You need to make a variable copy (Swift 3 compatible):

```
func receivedData(pChData: UInt8, andLength len: CInt) {
    var pChData = pChData
    var receivedData: Byte = Byte()
    var receivedDataLength: CInt = 0

    memcpy(&receivedData, &pChData, Int(len));  // Getting the error here
    receivedDataLength = len
    AudioHandler.sharedInstance.receiverAudio(&receivedData, WithLen: receivedDataLength)
}
```

or, with Swift 2, you can add `var` to the argument:

```
func receivedData(var pChData: UInt8, andLength len: CInt) {
    var receivedData: Byte = Byte()
    var receivedDataLength: CInt = 0

    memcpy(&receivedData, &pChData, Int(len));  // Getting the error here
    receivedDataLength = len
    AudioHandler.sharedInstance.receiverAudio(&receivedData, WithLen: receivedDataLength)
}
```

Third option, but that's not what you're asking for: make the argument an inout. But it will also mutate pchData *outside* of the func, so it looks like you don't want this here - this is not in your question (but I could have read that wrong of course).